# How to loop over Angular FormArray - currently sets as last item in loop

Tags: javascript, angular, closures

I'm trying to loop though a FormArray setting values. Fairly new to javascript.

Below `TeamWorkingDate` is set to the same date for each of the 7 FormGroup's in the `Team` FormArray, and is set to the last in the loop, date + 7 days.

I've tried many variations of forEach and answers @ [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) as I believe this must be some closure issue.

My understanding of closures is limited despite reading up on this. In this instance - is it that `setValue` has access to the variable i outside the function call and so is 'seeing' i = 7? I thought `let` stops this issue?

```
  setDates(date: moment) {
    var arr = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      let nextDate = date.clone().add(i, 'day');
      arr.push(nextDate);
      (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('Teams')).controls[i]
        .get('TeamWorkingDate').setValue(arr[i]);
    }
  }
```

My Form:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Teams: this.fb.array([])
    });
    const team = this.fb.group({
      TeamWorkingDate: '',
      ...
    })
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('Teams')).push(team);
    }
  }
```

EDIT: changed to `let nextDate = date.clone().add(i, 'day');` instead of `var`

Comment: Yes, `let` stops the issue you are talking about and IMK, `setValue()` is not an async call, so that shouldn't event be a problem. What is the issue you are facing can you explain more, I didn't get the question.

Comment: I want to set the `TeamWorkingDate`, a FormGroup in a FormArray (7 appended OnInit) to `date`, `date+1 day`, etc but I'm just getting this set to `date+7 days` for all of them.

Comment: What is `date.clone()`? Does it really gives a newDate and doesn't modify the existing date?

Comment: date is a moment (mutable), yes clone makes a copy...https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/

Comment: @miselking Great catch! didn't see that..

Comment: Yes, but still I don't know if that will work... Btw, I removed the comment, it was:
Replace `var nextDate = ...` with `let nextDate = ...`

Comment: didn't work, updated post

Comment: @AndrewAllen Why do you have the same group pushed in the formArray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently all the formGroups in the formArray are pointing to the same FormGroup reference, so changing value at any index will effectively update the same group.  Create and push new FormGroups in the formArray.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      Teams: this.fb.array([])
    });
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const team = this.fb.group({
      TeamWorkingDate: '',
        ...
      })
      (<FormArray>this.myForm.get('Teams')).push(team);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Getting `ERROR TypeError: this.fb.group(...) is not a function` but accepted as at least I know now what's wrong

Comment: @AndrewAllen Isn't `FormBuilder` injected in your component as `fb`?

Comment: you mean like `constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, `?

Comment: @AndrewAllen yes, thats correct. It of type `FormBuilder` and of course that is why you have been able to create the form and add values to it. It may be just your editor which might not be recognizing the type. You aren't getting any compiletime/runtime errors right?

Comment: just needed a semicolon.